# Batch file quits unexpectedly

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to make a bat file that will grab a git repository and download it to a specific directory.

The error I get when running this script is:

```
' was unexpected at this time.
```

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
TITLE Starter Kit
cls

echo "Note: This script will download the 'CodeKit-Starter-Kit' repository from @NicholasAdamou's GitHub."
set /p response="Do you want to continue? <y/n>"

if /i "%response%"=="y" (
    goto :downloadKit

    :downloadKit
    cls
    echo "Downloading the CodeKit-Starter-Kit repository from @NicholasAdamou's GitHub."
    set "filePath=%~dp0"
    cd %filePath%
    cd ../dist
    git clone https://github.com/NicholasAdamou/CodeKit-Starter-Kit.git 'StarterKit (CodeKit)'
)

if /i "%response%"=="n" (
    call exit
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis of the git line, like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/NicholasAdamou/CodeKit-Starter-Kit.git 'StarterKit (CodeKit^)'
```

This is because batch views closing parenthesis as special characters

Comment: Thanks for your answer...it makes more sense.

Comment: Not absolutely sure, but as far as I can remember, `git` also accepts doublequotes, so this should work as well: `git clone https://github.com/NicholasAdamou/CodeKit-Starter-Kit.git "StarterKit (CodeKit)"`; so there is no need to escape anything...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand 
    set "filePath=%~dp0"

Try to substitute single quotes in git command with doublequotes .

Anyway , we  are in 2016  , it's time to learn powershell :-)

```
$filepath="$home\\dp0"
read-host -prompt "Do you want download it ? " -outvariable response
if ( $response -eq "y"){
     set-location "$filepath\\dist"
     git clone https://github.com/NicholasAdamou/CodeKit-Starter-Kit.git 'StarterKit (CodeKit)'
}
```

Comment: In response to this: I don't understand set "filePath=%~dp0" I was trying to get the script to set the location to the cwd of the file. I have tried, "Try to substitute single quotes in git command with double quotes." The result didn't work. So I'll try your snippet and see if that works.

Comment: As for the `"filePath=%~dp0"`, It's batch code meaning set the variable filepath to contain the path of the current batch-file